# What is the difference between 'remove' and 'removeChild' method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML page to understand how removing an element works.

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var childDiv = null;
      var parent1 = null;
      var parent2 = null;
      function init() {
        childDiv = document.getElementById("child");
        parent1 = document.getElementById("parent1");
        parent2 = document.getElementById("parent2");
      }

      function rem() {
        if (childDiv) {
          childDiv.remove();
          alert("child removed");
        } else {
          alert("child does not exist");
        }
      }

      function remChild() {
        if (childDiv){
          if (parent1.children.length > 0) {
            parent1.removeChild(childDiv);
            alert("child unbound from parent");
          } else {
            alert("child exists but is not bound to parent");
          }
        } else {
          alert("child does not exist");

        }
      }

      function ins() {
        if (childDiv) {
          parent2.appendChild(childDiv);

          alert("child inserted to another parent");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="parent1">
      <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="parent2"></div>
    <button onclick="rem()">remove</button>
    <button onclick="remChild()">removeChild</button>
    <button onclick="ins()">insert</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I try to remove the 'child' div in two ways:

1. By calling 'remove' method on 'child' div
2. By calling 'removeChild' method on 'parent1' node

But in both the cases, the node is not actually removed. I can always insert 'child' div to 'parent2'.

I can understand that in second case, the 'child' is unbound from 'parent1' and not actually deleted. But in first case, is the 'child' not removed permanently?

Shouldn't I get an error while trying to insert an element which does not exist?

Please explain.

And if the element does exist even after calling 'remove' on element:

1. How is 'remove' different from 'removeChild'? As I see, both these methods just unbound child from parent, but element still occupies the memory.
2. Is there any way to ensure that element is actually removed from memory?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> the node is not actually removed

The confusion might be because you might think removing an element means something like killing or destroying it.

[image]

But in fact, the concept of [removal](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node-remove) basically means breaking the relationship between a child and its parent. It's just a detachment.

[image]

> Shouldn't I get an error while trying to insert an element which does not exist?

No, because it still exists.

> How is `remove` different from `removeChild`?

`remove` only needs a reference to the child. `removeChild` needs a reference both to the parent and the child. The result is identical.

> Is there any way to ensure that element is actually removed from memory?

No. You can only unreference it and hope that there is a garbage collector which will detect the object is not referenced and then will remove it.

Comment: what will happen to event listeners attached to a node, assume we have an inline arrow function attached, now there is no direct way to use removeEventListener, does the garbage collector will automatically remove it, or it will be there in memory(I have already gone through several articles). Thanks

Comment: @WasitShafi you can't remove an anonymous inline event handler function unless you keep a reference to it. it does not matter if it's added to the dom or not. if it is a strong reference then it should not be garbage collected. if it is a weak reference then it should be garbage collected. you can test this to make sure. add a anonymous function to a click event then detach the node. maybe check memory size, then later add the node back. see if the click event is still there and check memory size again. 1/2

Comment: The way it works is if there are no references to the functions, then garbage collection should remove the object. If there are strong references, like the handler is declared on the document body, then it should not get garbage collected. If there is a way to trigger the garbage collect (would be nice) then you could see that. My guess and experience is that nodes will stay in memory for the entire browser session but I have no way to prove this at this time. I know mobile browsers may try GC more often. And it may work different between browsers. Ask a separate question for more details 2/2

Answer (score 12):

`remove` is a new function. It's a shortcut, making it simpler to remove an element without having to look for the parent node. It's unfortunately not available on old versions of Internet Explorer so, unless you don't want to support this browser, you'll have to use `removeChild` or use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill).

The reason the child element is kept in memory is **your code** keeps a reference to it.

If you do

```
childDiv = null;
```

then there's no reference pointing to it and the browser can free the memory.

Comment: I tried removing 'child' via 'removeChild' and removed the reference to it as well. This time element was removed permanently as well. I could not get 'child' back. So 'removeChild' doesn't just unbound the element from parent but actually removes it? I was able to get 'child' because of reference I had kept in code? So its just about keeping reference count: just like keeping a track of how many pointers point to an object? As soon as reference count is 0, the memory is freed?

Comment: Just FYI, 'remove' is available on IE 11.

Comment: @Prasoon More globally, any value that isn't accessible (using a reference or a DOM function) can be freed by the engine (and will usually be).