# What is the difference between parentNode.removeChild() and remove()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am developing a website. There are a lot of spots, where I have to remove the html element. The previous, main contributor used to do it like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('element');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

I'm wondering why didn't he just use

```
elem.remove();
```

instead.

I've gotten to the point, where the first method didn't work and returned an error, but the second one worked perfectly. Of course I wanted to stick with the code standard in this project, so my first try was to use parentNode.removeChild. Unfortunatelly I cannot contact that person to ask why is it done like that.

What is the difference between these two and can I safely replace those?

Comment: Give us more information about the error you got, it is very unexpected for this to throw.

Comment: Likely `parentNode` was `null` by removing the element multiple times.

Comment: @all plz consider in your answers->what will happen to event listeners attached to a node, assume we have an inline arrow function attached, now there is no direct way to use removeEventListener, does the garbage collector will automatically remove it, or it will be there in memory(I have already gone through several articles). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from MDN, the two are equivalent. The `.remove()` was inspired by jQuery and was implemented much later. IE does not support it.

---

If you don't need IE, you can safely replace `parentNode.removeChild`, but if you will transpile the code, the `replace` method have polyfill using `parentNode.removeChild` method...

Answer (score 0):

[Source of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998877/what-is-the-difference-between-remove-and-removechild-method-is-javascript)

How is remove different from removeChild?

`remove` only needs a reference to the child. `removeChild` needs a reference both to the parent and the child. The result is identical.

Also you might think ,Is there any way to ensure that element is actually removed from memory?

No. You can only unreference it and hope that there is a garbage collector which will detect the object is not referenced and then will remove it.

Comment: You could atleast have added the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998877/what-is-the-difference-between-remove-and-removechild-method-is-javascript) for the *copy-paste* answer.

Comment: @JavaScript here you go mate! 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: If a question is already answered on Stack Overflow, the correct action is to flag it as a duplicate, not to copy the answer from question to question. Please flag this question so that it can correctly be closed with a link to the answer so that it is helpful for other users also.