# JavaScript querySelectorAll() still discovers DOM elements that have been removed

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component

### The Problem

I'm creating a treasure hunt web app that allows you to dynamically add and remove point from the hunt. I do this through the .createElement() and .remove() methods respectively.

When all points have been configured, I grab all the elements (each node is created with a custom web component) with a querySelectorAll(), iterate through them, grab all the info (title, location, clue etc.) and create an object for each point, which is then put in an array. However, if I remove a node before or after I try to save, the deleted element is not removed from the list returned by querySelectorAll(). It throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector(...) is null

when reaching the point of any deleted points.

##### Method for web component removal

```
// Deletes point marker
deletePoint() {
    const delPoint = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".del-btn");
    let pointMarker = delPoint.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    pointMarker.remove();
};
```

##### Add and save functions

```
const addPoint = document.querySelector(".add");
const savePoints = document.querySelector(".save");
var data = [];
// Defines markers in preperation for later
let markers = null

// Adds point-marker element to markers div
addPoint.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const pointContainer = document.querySelector(".markers");
    const node = document.createElement("point-marker");
    pointContainer.appendChild(node);
});

// Grabs all point-marker elements, grabs relevant data and adds it to data array
savePoints.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // clears data
    data = []
    markers = document.querySelectorAll("point-marker");
    // Iterates through markers
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log(`i: ${i}`)
        // Grabs all relevant info
        let name = markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector(".name").textContent;
        let location = markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector(".location").textContent;
        let clue = markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector("#clue").value;
        // Saves all relevant info in object form
        point = {
            id: `${i}`,
            name: `${name}`,
            location: `${location} ${i}`,
            clue: `${clue}`
        }
        // Adds point to data
        data.push(point)
    }
    console.log(data)
});
```

I'm fairly certain it's an issue with the .remove() method not fully removing the element from the DOM, as it doesn't cause an issue when an element is added, but cannot find another method.

Here's the full code as a snippet if it's of any help:

```js
// === script.js ====
// Declares template variable, containing the html template for the component
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
        .point-marker {
            color: var(--tertiary-color);
            background-color: var(--secondary-color);
            padding: 2rem;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin: 1rem 0;
        }
        
        .point-marker h2 {
            line-height: 1rem;
        }
        
        .point-marker textarea {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            resize: vertical;
            padding: .5rem;
            margin: 1rem 0;
        }
        
        .btn {
            background-color: var(--primary-color);
            border: none;
            padding: .5rem 1rem;
            min-width: 200px;
            color: var(--tertiary-color);
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: medium;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .del-btn {
            background-color: var(--fail-color);
        }
        
        .btns {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        
        .coll-content {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 250ms ease-in-out;
        }
        
        .collapse-icon {
            font-size: large;
        }
        
        .const-content {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <section class="point-marker">
    <div class="const-content">
        <h2 class="name">New Point</h2>
        <i class="fas fa-minus collapse-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="coll-content">
        <p>Location: <p class="location">location</p></p>
        <p>Clue:</p>
        <textarea name="clue" id="clue" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div class="btns">
            <button class="btn loc-btn">SET CURRENT LOCATION</button>
            <button class="btn del-btn">DELETE POINT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
`;

// Declares class PointMarker and casts it as an HTML element
class PointMarker extends HTMLElement {
  // Initialises the class every time new object is made
  constructor() {
    super();

    //  Declares shadow DOM and sets it to open
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });

    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));


    setTimeout(() => {
      const coll = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".const-content");
      coll.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = `${coll.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight}px`;
    }, 100)

    const name = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".name")
    name.contentEditable = "true";


  };

  // Collapses or expands the collapsable content
  expandCollapse() {
    const coll = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".const-content");
    let content = coll.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = `${content.scrollHeight + 30}px`;
    };
  };

  // Deletes point marker
  deletePoint() {
    this.disconnectedCallback();
    const delPoint = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".del-btn");
    let pointMarker = delPoint.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    pointMarker.remove();
    pointMarker = null;
  };

  // Adds event listener on all elements with class of const-content or del-btn
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".collapse-icon").addEventListener("click", () => this.expandCollapse());
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".del-btn").addEventListener("click", () => this.deletePoint());
    console.log("connectedCallback() called");
    console.log(this.isConnected)
  };

  // Adds event listener on all elements with class of del-btn
  disconnectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".collapse-icon").removeEventListener("click", () => this.expandCollapse());
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".del-btn").removeEventListener("click", () => this.deletePoint());
    console.log("disconnectedCallback() called");
    console.log(this.isConnected)
  };
};

// Defines <point-marker>
window.customElements.define("point-marker", PointMarker);

const addPoint = document.querySelector(".add");
const savePoints = document.querySelector(".save");
// Defines markers in preperation for later

// Adds point-marker element to markers div
addPoint.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const pointContainer = document.querySelector(".markers");
  const node = document.createElement("point-marker");
  pointContainer.appendChild(node);
});

// Grabs all point-marker elements, grabs relevant data and adds it to data array
savePoints.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // clears data
  let data = []
  markers = document.querySelectorAll("point-marker");

  // Iterates through markers
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    // Grabs all relevant info
    let name = markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector(".name").textContent;
    let location = markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector(".location").textContent;
    let clue = markers[i].shadowRoot.querySelector("#clue").value;

    // Saves all relevant info in object form
    let point = {}
    point = {
      id: `${i}`,
      name: `${name}`,
      location: `${location} ${i}`,
      clue: `${clue}`
    }

    // Adds point to data
    data.push(point)
    console.log(data)
  }
  return data;
});
```

```css
/* style.css */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
:root {
  --primary-color: #FA4D05;
  --secondary-color: #333;
  --tertiary-color: #fff;
  --success-color: #97FD87;
  --fail-color: #FF5555;
  --bg-color: #E5E5E5;
  --font-color: #808080;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  line-height: 2;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 65px;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  /* color: var(--primary-color); */
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 50%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem;
}

main h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  border: none;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  min-width: 200px;
  color: var(--tertiary-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: medium;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-point {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--font-color);
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.save {
  background-color: var(--success-color);
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Create A Hunt</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h2>HOME</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2>HUNT</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>CREATE</h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h1>CREATE A HUNT</h1>
    <div class="markers">
    </div>

    <button class="btn add-point add">
            <h2>Add Point +</h2>
        </button>

    <button class="btn add-point save">
            <h2>Save Points</h2>
        </button>

  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/pointMarker.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### TL;DR

Elements removed with the .remove() method are still picked up by the .querySelectorAll() method, presumably because it does not remove it from the DOM fully.

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998877/what-is-the-difference-between-remove-and-removechild-method-in-javascript

Comment: @AmitDas it does seem to be the garbage collector's innefficiency. I've tried setting the object to null afterwards, but to no avail.

Comment: Is it because you don't declare 'point'??

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman tried declaring point with no avail. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Use the [ < > ] button in de SO editor to convert your code to executable format. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  // Deletes point marker
  deletePoint() {
    this.disconnectedCallback();
    const delPoint = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".del-btn");
    let pointMarker = delPoint.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    pointMarker.remove();
    pointMarker = null;
 };
```

This does not remove the point marker. It removes the contents of the point marker but the point marker is still there.

```js
  // Deletes point marker
  deletePoint() {
    this.disconnectedCallback();
    this.remove();
  };
```

This removes the actual element from the page, and your code then works just fine.

Comment: ``this.remove()`` triggers the ``this.disconnectedCallback()`` so the above code runs the ``disconnectedCallback`` twice